# Choose the right algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o

I have this problem:
there is a integer vector of N elements, I call it `A`.
Then there are two elements, I call them `(P,Q)`, such that `0<= P <= Q <N` (`P,Q` are indexes of `A`).
We use the two elements to compute `L = A[P] + A[Q] + (Q-P)`.

I have to compute the maximum value of `L` using an algorithm with complexity O(n) and using O(1) memory.

This is my solution but I think it is `O(n^2)`:

```
int L = 0;

for(int i=0; i<A.size(); i++) {
  for(int j=i; j<A.size(); j++) {
    L = max(L, A[i] +A[j] +(j-i) );  
  }
}

cout<<"Best: "<<L<<endl;
```

Do you have better algorithms to solve this problem?

**Edit**
This is a simple example:

```
A = [-8,4,0,5,-3,6]
```

The result should be `L = 14` `( A[1] +A[5] +(5-1) )`

**Final Solution**

```
int solve_A_2_002(const std::vector<int>& A) {
    int P = A[0];
    int P_i = 0; //index

    int Q = A[0];
    int Q_i = 0;

    int L = P+P;

    int temp1,temp2, temp3;

    for(int i=0; i<A.size(); i++) {
        temp1 = A[i] + P + (i - P_i);
        temp2 = A[i] + Q + (i - Q_i);
        temp3 = A[i] + A[i];

        if(L < temp1) {
            L = temp1;
            Q_i = i; //save new couple (P,Q)
            Q = A[i];
        }

        if(L < temp2) {
            L = temp2;
            P_i = i;
            P = A[i];
        }

        if(L < temp3) {
            L = temp3;
            P_i = Q_i = i;
            Q = P = A[i];

        }
    }

    return L;
}
```

Comment: Potentially interesting, but as asked (& with poor title) it's just a broad homework stink.

Comment: As MikeMB mentioned in comments of my answer, and I updated in the answer, there is one more check, `(A[i], A[i])`. I did not see that `P` can equal to `Q` in the original problem. Also, for the same reason, algorithm should start with `P=Q=0`.

Comment: As an additional exercise, try to find an example where the current "final solution" gives wrong output, exploiting the details from the previous comment.

Comment: Ops! I update the "final solution"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't really prove it (and it's late here), but the algorithm should take first element as `P` and `Q`, (`P=0`, `Q=0`), and iterate the rest of the array, and for each element `E` calculate `L` for just three pairs, `(P, E)`, `(Q, E)` and `(E, E)`. If one of them is larger than old `(P, Q)` then take that pair as new `P` and `Q`.

Comment: Probably can be proved by induction and proof by contradiction.

Comment: @user72708 please provide an example where algorithm does not work. I would like to see into it.

Answer (score 3):

One common thing to do when you're doing something with all combinations of *two* variables but still want subquadratic time is to try and split whatever you're doing apart into two *one*-variable things.

In this case, that's rather simple:

```
L = (A[P] - P) + (A[Q] + Q);
```

and we can obviously maximize this quantity in linear time and constant memory by maximize the two pieces. But the problem we can obviously solve is a simplified one: the real problem has an additional constraint `P <= Q`.

In general, we have to do some more work to take the things we can compute simply and combine them to produce an answer to the problem we want. Sometimes this further analysis can be somewhat sophisticated, or require some clever ways to combine the things we can easily compute into a solution to the problem we actually care about.

In this case, though, the solution to the simplified problem we can easily solve *is* the solution to the original problem. An easy way to see this is to write

```
A[x] - x = (A[x] + x) - 2x
```

from which it's easy to see that if `x=Q` is a value that maximizes `A[x] + x`, then making `x>Q` must yield a smaller value for `A[x] - x`.

Comment: `P` and `Q` aren't independent though - OP requires `P<=Q`. But the approach still works in this case because of the actual functions. Perhaps you could edit that in.

Comment: "... you just need to do a little bit of extra analysis to check if this gives you something satisfying your constraints on P and Q, and if not how to adjust the search to account for them."  Unless you can give a sketch of how that could be done in linear time and constant overhead, this isn't a complete answer.

Comment: @jschultz410 Hurkyl as Pradhan hinted, the solution will automatically satisfy the condition `P<=Q`, but I agree that this part of the answer isn't really helpfull.

Comment: @MikeMB Yeah, I eventually proved that to myself.  Find P that maximizes A[P] - P (1) and Q that maximizes A[Q] + Q (2) .  Because P maximizes (1), A[P] - P >= A[Q] - Q => A[P] - A[Q] >= P - Q.  Because Q maximizes (2), A[Q] + Q >= A[P] + P => A[P] - A[Q] <= Q - P.  Putting those two relations together yields: P - Q <= A[P] - A[Q] <= Q - P.  Now assume P > Q.  The relation becomes: 1 <= A[P] - A[Q] <= -1, which is a contradiction, while P <= Q yields no such contradiction.  But that wasn't readily apparent to me to always be true.  Can you give any insight that makes it more obvious?

Comment: @jschultz: My outline was "if `x` maximizes `A[x] + x`, then no value larger than `x` can maximize `A[x] - x`". The simplest formalization of how I rationalized that is to write `A[x] - x = (A[x] + x) + (-2x)`, and observe that increasing `x` cannot increase the first term but always decreases the second term. I was trying to give advice on how to approach this sort of thing in general: sometimes it's not so simple but further analysis can reduce the problem to searching a small number of cases, or a path to iterate through `P` and `Q` that is guaranteed to meet the answer, or somesuch.

Comment: Would actually be interesting, whether one can solve the problem for Q < P in linear time.

Comment: @MikeMB: Linear time is relatively easy: make a table `B[x] = max{A[y] - y | y > x}`. Keeping the constant memory requirement too makes it harder!